# Project file changes causing `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Tags: bug, projectconfig

I switched over to use project file settings and now I occasionally get a constraint violation when trying to run the `craft projectconfig/sync` command.

I think this is a bug, because the

```
UPDATE `info` SET `id`=1, `version`='3.3.0.1', `schemaVersion`='3.3.3', `maintenance`=0, `config`=' ...`
```

statement seem to be missing a WHERE, which means it tries to set ALL rows in table `info` to the same values. For some reason, I end up having 2 rows in `info` where the one with id=2 is basically empty.

This is on version 3.3.0.1.

Invoking a `DELETE FROM info WHERE id = 2;` resolves the situation in my case, but it is a bit cumbersome that this happens.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the `craft_info` table should only have one row.

This would mean that either:

1. You have something installed / configured wrongly somewhere causing it to insert a 2nd row into the table
2. Or it's actually a craft bug, I'd advise you to search through [The CraftCMS Github Issues](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) and check if there's any issue resembling yours, if not create an issue there so it gets solved in the next few updates.